# Wait for Async callback during Electron preload script

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I am trying to fetch cookies from the default session and add them to a webpage loaded via a webview electron tag. So I use a preload script - like

```
<webview src="http://localhost:3500" preload="./lib/my-preload.js"></webview>
```

My preload script looks like the following

```
const { session } = require('electron').remote;


session.defaultSession.cookies.get({ name : 'templates' } , (error,cookies) => {
    console.log('RETURN');
    if(error)
        throw error;
    else{
        console.log(cookies[0].value );
        window.myTemplates = JSON.parse( cookies[0].value );

    }
});
```

However - the async callback is never reached. When I do the following, it allows me to access the session cookies

```
let getTemplates = (callbackFn ) => {
session.defaultSession.cookies.get({ name : 'templates' } , (error,cookies) => {
    if(error)
        throw error;
    else{
        callbackFn( cookies[0].value );

    }
});
};
window.getTemplates = getTemplates;
```

When I call the getTemplates function from a webview page script, it acts as expected.
However, I need the cookies available before any of my other scripts load. Is there a way to force nodejs to wait for the async callback of the **get** function to return before discarding the preload script